# Databases lost after Postgres upgrade from 11 to 12

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, upgrade

This is not my first upgrade. In the past I upgraded from 9 to 10 and 10 to  11. I thought that I wrote everything down the last time but apparently not. In verion 11 my databases are in `nl_BE.utf-8`:

```
                              List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+
 glewlwyd  | glewlwyd | UTF8     | nl_BE.utf-8 | nl_BE.utf-8 |
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | nl_BE.utf-8 | nl_BE.utf-8 | 
 prda      | postgres | UTF8     | nl_BE.utf-8 | nl_BE.utf-8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | nl_BE.UTF-8 | nl_BE.UTF-8 |
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | nl_BE.utf-8 | nl_BE.utf-8 |

(5 rows)
```

After the installation (`apt-get install postgresql-12`) I modify the `/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf` and change the `en_US.UTF-8` into `nl_BE.UTF-8`. In the previous upgrades I copied this file to my data directory but 12 does not seem to like that. The port number of the 11 and 12 version differ.

When I create the database with `/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/initdb --locale=nl_BE.UTF-8 --pgdata=/srv/postgres/data/12` the new instance is created but the databases are in `en_US.UTF-8`. The `/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_upgrade -b /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin -B /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin -d /srv/postgres/data/11 -D /srv/postgres/data/12` ends without an error.

When I connect to the instance my own databases are not there. Must be because the locale is not correct. I also changed the locale (`export LANG=nl_BE.UTF-8`) of my shell but this did not help. What could I have done wrong?

Comment: If installing from the APT repository, why don't you use `pg_upgradecluster` instead?

Comment: I never thought about that. I need to see what the parameters look like

Comment: Do you mean that when passing `--locale=nl_BE.UTF-8`, initdb displayed: _The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8"_ ?

Comment: It said that `nl_BE.UTF-8` was going to be used. My problem is solved by the comment from Colin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the comment from @Colin 't Hart and this solved the problem. With `pg_upgradecluster -v 12 11 main /srv/postgres/data/12` the upgrade was done. I changed the port to `5432` and restarted it. Now my applications are using the version 12 database.